# nonmonotone line search-Why might a non-monotone line search not be satisfied

Tags: optimization

The line search criteria are as follows: Parameters $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\sigma$, and $\delta$ are introduced where $0 < \lambda_1 < \lambda_2$ and $\sigma, \delta \in (0, 1)$, and they set $\alpha_k = \overline{\alpha_k} \sigma^{h_k}$ where $\overline{\alpha_k} \in (\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ is the "trial step" and $h_k$ is the smallest nonnegative integer such that
$$f(x_k + \alpha_k d_k) \le \max_{0 \le j \le m_k}f(x_{k-j}) + \delta\alpha_k \nabla f(x_k)d_k.\tag{1.2} \label{eq:1.2}$$
Here the gradient of $f$ at $x_k$, $\nabla f(x_k)$, is a row vector. The memory $m_k$ at step $k$ is a nondecreasing integer, bounded by some fixed integer $M$. More precisely, $m_0 = 0$ and for $k > 0$, $0 \le m_k \le \min(m_{k−1} + 1, M)$.

But why "although an iterative method is generating $\mathbb R$-linearly
convergent iterations for a strongly convex function, the iterates may not satisfy the condition \eqref{eq:1.2} for $k$ sufficiently large, for any fixed bound $M$ on the memory."
The example is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2, x\in \mathbb R ,  x_0 \ne 0, d_k=-x_k,$$
and
$α_k =1-2^{-k}x^2$, if $k = i^2$ for some integer $i$, otherwise $α_k=2$ .

The iterates converge R-superlinearly to the minimizer $x^* = 0$; however, condition \eqref{eq:1.2} is not satisfied for $k$ sufficiently large and any fixed $M$.

I can't understand why this counterexample doesn't work. Thanks.

This example can be found in *[Y. H. Dai, On the nonmonotone line search, J. Optim. Theory Appl., 112 (2002), pp. 315–330.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1013653923062)* Formula (51) (52) on page 324.

Comment: Doesn't the paper say $\alpha_k = 1 - 2^{-k}$ (without the $x^2$)?

Comment: So if I choose $\delta = \frac{1}{2}$ for simplicity and assume that $k = i^2$ for some integer $i$, then (1.2) becomes $(4^{-k} + 1 - 2^{-k}) x_k^2 \le \max_{0 \le j \le m_k} x_{k - j}^2$ and if $k$ is not a square, then it becomes $3 x_k^2 \le \max_{0 \le j \le m_k} x_{k - j}^2$. Does this help?